# Masstransit: send message to all consumers and wait for response from them

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

On one side I got a custom web page, that sends to me some number of messages for my testing purposes. On another side, I got 4 consumers, that listen to the same queue (round-robin pattern).

Each consumer needs to do a great job, after receiving the message, such as read message, encode the string and create a file, launch another application, send email to a customer.

If I run my solution for one consumer, it works great. But if try to do the same for more then one consumer, I got exceptions.

All I try to do is if I got many messages in a queue, send a message to each consumer and wait for the response from them. Do it while I got messages in a queue.

I will be happy if someone can help me and show where can I find such kind of information or some example.

Comment: You are going to break rules on pub/sub. Producers should not know their consumers. When "all consumers": the producer need to know them (or the amount) to wait for "them all". Rethink your design!

Comment: It is the Scatter-Gatter pattern. Currently you can only do it with a saga.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to send messages sequentially to each queue, so that there is an equal number of messages

Answer (score 0):

You can achive what you are trying to do using a Saga.

Here is [the MassTransit documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/sagas/).

And here is [a Saga sample project](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ShoppingWeb).